# iText and Graphics2D: How to choose other font then Arial?

Tags: fonts, itext, pdf-generation

I use iText to create PDFs with graphics, including text. For this I use Graphics2D. But drawString ignores any selection of fonts, it always uses Arial.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new  FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\test.pdf");
Document document = null;
Rectangle rect=PageSize.A3.rotate();
document = new Document(rect);
PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
Graphics2D g =cb.createGraphics(rect.getWidth(),rect.getHeight());

Font font=new Font(“Times New Roman“,Font.PLAIN,10);
    // here the font-Variable shows the correct font
g.setFont(font);
Font checkFont=g.getFont();
    // here checkFont is correctly Times New Roman
g.drawString(“Merry Christmas!”,100,200);
…
```

But the text is always printed as Arial in the PDF-file, whatever font I specify.

Comment: Sure that "Times **Nes** Roman" is right?

Comment: Yes - this is a misstype, thank you, because I shrinked my code. This should be "Times New Roman" - and does not work.
I've corrected it in the code snipplet above, too.

Comment: Other ideas?
E.g. FontFactory seems not to work, if one uses the AWT drawString...

Thank you for further ideas! :-)

Comment: Stack overflow questions and answers are expected to be as short and on point as possible. Strict interpretation thereof makes people remove such niceties as thank-yous.